# Strategy pattern and two repositories

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, repository, factory-pattern, strategy-pattern

I have a strategy pattern in my business logic, which is referenced to two application. One is a Web MVC application and the other one is a Xamarin App.

Now I want to write / read data from the database in this strategy pattern, but I have two different repository. How can I inject the right one into this strategy pattern.

[image]

```
public class LearnStrategy
{
    private ILearnStrategy _learnStrategy = new SimpleLearnStrategy();

    public Guid CardSetId { get; set; }
    public string CardSetName { get; set; }

    public bool Shuffle { get; set; }
    public bool WriteMode { get; set; }

    public bool ReverseMode { get; set; }
    public int SelectedLearnLevel { get; set; }


    public void Execute()
    {
        _learnStrategy.StartLearn();
    }

    public void SetLearnStrategy(ILearnStrategy learningStrategy)
    {
        _learnStrategy = learningStrategy;
    }

    public ILearnStrategy GetStrategy()
    {
        return _learnStrategy;
    }

    public ILearnStrategy ResolveLearnStrategy(LearnModus learnModus)
    {
        switch (learnModus)
        {
            case LearnModus.Exam:
                return new ExamLearnStrategy();
            case LearnModus.Level:
                return new LevelLearnStrategy();
            case LearnModus.Simple:
                return new SimpleLearnStrategy();
            case LearnModus.System:
                return new SystemLearnStrategy();
            default:
                return new SimpleLearnStrategy();
        }
    }
}
```

And one of the strategy

```
public class SimpleLearnStrategy : ILearnStrategy
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void StartLearn()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

UPDATE

---

REPOSITORY A

```
public interface IRepositoryA<TEntityType> : IDisposable where
    TEntityType : class
{
    TEntityType Add(TEntityType entity);
    Task<TEntityType> AddAsync(TEntityType entity);
    void Update(TEntityType entity);
    Task UpdateAsync(TEntityType entity);
    void Delete(TEntityType entity);
    void Delete(Expression<Func<TEntityType, bool>> where);
    TEntityType GetById(Guid id);
    Task<TEntityType> GetByIdAsync(Guid id);
    TEntityType Get(Expression<Func<TEntityType, bool>> where);
    Task<TEntityType> GetAsync(Expression<Func<TEntityType, bool>> where, params Expression<Func<TEntityType, object>>[] includeProperties);
    IEnumerable<TEntityType> GetAll();
   // IEnumerable<TEntityType> GetMany(Expression<Func<TEntityType, bool>> where);
    //Task<IEnumerable<TEntityType>> GetManyAsync(Expression<Func<TEntityType, bool>> where,
    //    params Expression<Func<TEntityType, object>>[] includeProperties);
    int Count(Expression<Func<TEntityType, bool>> where);

    IEnumerable<TEntityType> GetMany(Func<IQueryable<TEntityType>, IQueryable<TEntityType>> includeMembers,Expression<Func<TEntityType, bool>> where);
    Task<IEnumerable<TEntityType>> GetManyAsync(Expression<Func<TEntityType, bool>> where);
}

public class RepositoryA<TEntityType> : IRepositoryA<TEntityType>
    where TEntityType : class
{
    readonly admin_MCCardContext _dbContext;
    private readonly DbSet<TEntityType> _dbSet;

    public Repository(admin_MCCardContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _dbSet = dbContext.Set<TEntityType>();
    }

    public TEntityType Add(TEntityType entity)
    {
    }

    public async Task<TEntityType> AddAsync(TEntityType entity)
    {
    }

    public void Update(TEntityType entity)
    {
    }

    public async Task UpdateAsync(TEntityType entity)
    {
    }

    public int Count(Expression<Func<TEntityType, bool>> where)
    {
    }

    public void Delete(TEntityType entity)
    {
    }

    public void Delete(Expression<Func<TEntityType, bool>> where)
    {
    }

    public TEntityType Get(Expression<Func<TEntityType, bool>> where)
    {
    }

    public async Task<TEntityType> GetAsync(Expression<Func<TEntityType, bool>> where,
        params Expression<Func<TEntityType, object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntityType> GetAll()
    {
    }

    public TEntityType GetById(Guid id)
    {
    }

    public async Task<TEntityType> GetByIdAsync(Guid id)
    {
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntityType> GetMany(Expression<Func<TEntityType, bool>> where)
    {
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntityType>> GetManyAsync(Expression<Func<TEntityType, bool>> where)
    {
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntityType> GetMany(Func<IQueryable<TEntityType>,IQueryable<TEntityType>> includeMembers,
        Expression<Func<TEntityType, bool>> where)
    {
    }

    private bool _disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this._disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _dbContext.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this._disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

REPOSITORY B

```
public interface IRepositoryB<T> : IDisposable where T : class, new()
{
    Task<T> GetAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);
    Task<List<T>> GetAsync();
    Task<T> GetAsync(Guid id);
    Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetListAsync<TValue>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where = null, Expression<Func<T, TValue>> orderBy = null);
    AsyncTableQuery<T> AsQueryable();
    Task<int> InsertAsync(T entity);
    Task<int> BulkSyncInsertAsync(IList<T> itemList);
    Task<int> UpdateAsync(T entity);
    Task<int> DeleteAsync(T entity);
    Task<int> CountAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);

    Task<bool> DeleteAllIdsAsync(string sqlQuery);
}

public class RepositoryB<TEntityType> : IRepositoryB<TEntityType> where TEntityType : class, new()
{
    private static readonly AsyncLock Locker = new AsyncLock();

    private SQLiteAsyncConnection DbContext { get; } = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetAsyncConnection();

    public Repository()
    {
    }

    public AsyncTableQuery<TEntityType> AsQueryable() => DbContext.Table<TEntityType>();

    public async Task<List<TEntityType>> GetAsync() => await DbContext.Table<TEntityType>().ToListAsync();

    public async Task<TEntityType> GetAsync(Expression<Func<TEntityType, bool>> where) => await DbContext.FindAsync<TEntityType>(where);

    public async Task<TEntityType> GetAsync(Guid id) => await DbContext.FindAsync<TEntityType>(id);

    public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntityType>> GetListAsync<TValue>(Expression<Func<TEntityType, bool>> where = null, Expression<Func<TEntityType, TValue>> orderBy = null)
    {
    }

    public async Task<int> InsertAsync(TEntityType entity) => await DbContext.InsertAsync(entity);

    public async Task<int> BulkSyncInsertAsync(IList<TEntityType> itemList)
    {
    }

    public async Task<int> CountAsync(Expression<Func<TEntityType, bool>> where)
    {
    }

    public async Task<int> UpdateAsync(TEntityType entity) => await DbContext.UpdateAsync(entity);

    public async Task<int> DeleteAsync(TEntityType entity) => await DbContext.DeleteAsync(entity);

    public async Task<bool> DeleteAllIdsAsync(string sqlQuery)
    {
    }

    private bool _disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this._disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().CloseConnection();
            }
        }
        this._disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Is there something that prevents you to create the corresponding repository inside each learning strategy ?

Comment: No not realy, but then I have to overgive the application (web or app) from which the call is coming. And then a if else... is that not ugly?

Comment: Ohh so you mean the repository is tied to which application is in use ?

Comment: yes exactly, when it comes from Web, the strategy pattern should use repositoryA and if it comes from App then the strategy pattern should use repositoryB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments it looks like you must use a given repository when the strategy is used either from the web or from an app.

The key here is to avoid trying to guess in which app one is but rather to delegate this responsibility further. This is where dependency injection shines: let the caller give you the correct repository !

First these two repositories have to be grouped under the same abstraction:

```
public interface IRepository<T> : IDisposable where T : class
{
    Task UpdateAsync(T entity);
    Task<int> CountAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);
}
public sealed class RepositoryA<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    public async Task<int> CountAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public void Dispose() => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public async Task UpdateAsync(T entity) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    //other methods not common to both repositories
}
public sealed class RepositoryB<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, new()
{
    public async Task<int> CountAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public void Dispose() => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public async Task UpdateAsync(T entity) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    //other methods not common to both repositories
}
```

Then this abstraction must be provided when constructing a strategy:

```
public ILearnStrategy ResolveLearnStrategy(LearnModus learnModus, IRepository repository)
{
    switch (learnModus)
    {
        case LearnModus.Exam:
            return new ExamLearnStrategy(repository);
        case LearnModus.Level:
            return new LevelLearnStrategy(repository);
        case LearnModus.Simple:
            return new SimpleLearnStrategy(repository);
        case LearnModus.System:
            return new SystemLearnStrategy(repository);
        default:
            return new SimpleLearnStrategy(repository);
    }
}
```

Each strategy must accept this repository and use it when needed (only 1 abstraction examplified for the sake of brevity):

```
public class SimpleLearnStrategy : ILearnStrategy
{
    private readonly IRepository _repository;
    public SimpleLearnStrategy(IRepository repository) => _repository = repository;
    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void StartLearn()
    {
        //use _repository for your needs
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1861065 If you share `RepositoryA` and `RepositoryB` I can help you to group them below a common interface.

Comment: Hey Spotted => I Updated my post and added the repos. They are not finished at the moment and for this reason a little messy... But thanks for your help

Comment: @user1861065 Ugh, they are rather big. Which methods from both do you need to use in each learn strategy ? The answer to this question will yield which method the `IRepository` interface I proposed will need.

Comment: Maybe at first, I should rename the same methods from each repo with the same method name. But if you could give me a sample with maybe UpdateAsync and CountAsync, then I can implement the other needed methods by me self.

Comment: @user1861065 I provided an canvas on how to do that. More I cannot do, I'm not an EF expert. Also note that I purposely removed `IRepositoryA` and `IRepositoryB` since I suspected they have only 1 implementation each (thus making them an useless layer of abstraction).

Comment: Thank you, after cleaning my repositories and other stuff it works!